# how to set date and time not depending on computer date and time?

Tags: php, date, time

Please help,I want to set my webpage date not based on computer time because what if the user's time is not set correctly. i have tried searching in google but unfortunately did not get my answer.

I tried this code but when i change my pc date and time it also changes the output in my webpage to my pc time.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
?>
```

Comment: PHP code runs on the server, not the users' computer!

Comment: If you don't want the time on the users browser or on the serve running PHP you'll need to investigate NTP servers and communicate with them.

Answer (score 0):

This would hardly be a problem, as the website code is run on the website server, which has its very own time and date setting. As long as you make sure the date/time setting of the server is correct you will be fine.

The date/time setting of visiting users sure can differ a lot, depending on the user's geographical location. It may cause trouble when running JavaScript on a webpage, but for server code (e.g. PHP) it would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The date will be set relative to the server that runs the code, if you run your code with a server instance on your computer, changing your computer date settings will afect your script but if you use a server wich is not on your computer the date setting that will be returned by your script will be the setting of your server not your computer's.